# Падает база postgresql

Tags: debian, postgresql9.6

Начала "падать" база несколько дней назад. 
Дано:
psql (PostgreSQL) 9.6.9
32 Gb ОЗУ,  8 ядер Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1270 v3 @ 3.50GHz

Log с момента запуска сервера:

```
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [16549-27] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [16549-28] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20359-11] FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20351-2] LOG:  autovacuum launcher shutting down
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20355-2] [unknown]@irzdb LOG:  manager worker [20355] at slot 0 generation 2 detaching cleanly
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20357-9] FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20356-23] FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20358-31] FATAL:  terminating autovacuum process due to administrator command
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [20348-1] LOG:  shutting down
2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC [16549-29] LOG:  database system is shut down
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20790-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2019-03-14 11:49:40 UTC
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20791-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20790-2] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20795-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20789-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20797-1] LOG:  starting pglogical supervisor
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20798-1] [unknown]@postgres LOG:  manager worker [20798] at slot 0 generation 1 detaching cleanly
2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC [20799-1] [unknown]@irzdb LOG:  starting pglogical database manager for database irzdb
2019-03-14 11:49:42 UTC [20806-1] [unknown]@template1 LOG:  manager worker [20806] at slot 1 generation 1 detaching cleanly
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-1] ERROR:  MultiXactId 374398121 has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_24140"
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-3] ERROR:  found xmax 735 from before relfrozenxid 575160892
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-4] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_24466"
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-5] ERROR:  found xmax 81 from before relfrozenxid 575187540
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-6] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_14818"
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-7] ERROR:  found xmax 117 from before relfrozenxid 575203658
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-8] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_19006"
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-9] ERROR:  found xmax 892 from before relfrozenxid 575221836
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-10] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_19970"
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-11] ERROR:  found xmin 3676210688 from before relfrozenxid 575237010
2019-03-14 11:53:02 UTC [21463-12] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_20801"
2019-03-14 11:53:04 UTC [21463-13] ERROR:  found xmax 438 from before relfrozenxid 575242479
2019-03-14 11:53:04 UTC [21463-14] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_20862"
2019-03-14 11:53:04 UTC [21463-15] ERROR:  found xmax 55387931 from before relfrozenxid 575277757
2019-03-14 11:53:04 UTC [21463-16] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_11109"
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-17] ERROR:  invalid page in block 8755 of relation base/16385/1508406
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-18] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_14016"
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-19] ERROR:  found xmax 636 from before relfrozenxid 575359580
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-20] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_16673"
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-21] ERROR:  invalid page in block 1955 of relation base/16385/1527429
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-22] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_19006"
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-23] ERROR:  found xmax 515 from before relfrozenxid 575423024
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-24] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_10723"
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-25] ERROR:  invalid page in block 47546 of relation base/16385/1551827
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-26] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_11615"
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-27] ERROR:  invalid page in block 11395 of relation base/16385/1553243
2019-03-14 11:53:05 UTC [21463-28] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_11863"
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [21463-29] PANIC:  corrupted item pointer: offset = 28672, length = 6939
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20789-2] LOG:  server process (PID 21463) was terminated by signal 6: Aborted
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20789-3] DETAIL:  Failed process was running: autovacuum: VACUUM public.z_io_12386 (to prevent wraparound)
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20789-4] LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20795-2] WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20795-3] DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20795-4] HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20869-1] radiofid@irzdb WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of another server process
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20869-2] radiofid@irzdb DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory.
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20869-3] radiofid@irzdb HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your command.
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [20789-5] LOG:  all server processes terminated; reinitializing
2019-03-14 11:53:58 UTC [21654-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-03-14 11:49:41 UTC
2019-03-14 11:54:00 UTC [21654-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2019-03-14 11:54:00 UTC [21654-3] LOG:  redo starts at 95D/93466080
2019-03-14 11:54:00 UTC [21654-4] LOG:  redo done at 95D/95B87408
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21654-5] LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21658-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [20789-6] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21660-1] LOG:  starting pglogical supervisor
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21661-1] [unknown]@postgres LOG:  manager worker [21661] at slot 0 generation 1 detaching cleanly
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21662-1] [unknown]@irzdb LOG:  starting pglogical database manager for database irzdb
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-1] ERROR:  MultiXactId 374398121 has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_24140"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-1] ERROR:  found xmax 735 from before relfrozenxid 575160892
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_24466"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21663-1] ERROR:  found xmax 81 from before relfrozenxid 575187540
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21663-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_14818"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-1] ERROR:  found xmax 117 from before relfrozenxid 575203658
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-2] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_19006"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-3] ERROR:  found xmax 892 from before relfrozenxid 575221836
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-4] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_19970"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-3] ERROR:  found xmin 3676210688 from before relfrozenxid 575237010
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-4] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_20801"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-3] ERROR:  found xmax 55387931 from before relfrozenxid 575277757
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-4] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_11109"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-5] ERROR:  invalid page in block 8755 of relation base/16385/1508406
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-6] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_14016"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-5] ERROR:  found xmax 636 from before relfrozenxid 575359580
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-6] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_16673"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-5] ERROR:  invalid page in block 1955 of relation base/16385/1527429
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-6] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_19006"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-7] ERROR:  found xmax 515 from before relfrozenxid 575423024
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21664-8] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_10723"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-7] ERROR:  invalid page in block 47546 of relation base/16385/1551827
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-8] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_11615"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-7] ERROR:  invalid page in block 11395 of relation base/16385/1553243
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21665-8] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_11863"
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-9] ERROR:  found xmax 545 from before relfrozenxid 575604035
2019-03-14 11:54:01 UTC [21666-10] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_12610"
2019-03-14 11:54:02 UTC [21666-11] ERROR:  found xmax 312 from before relfrozenxid 575664399
2019-03-14 11:54:02 UTC [21666-12] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_13053"
2019-03-14 11:54:02 UTC [21671-1] [unknown]@template1 LOG:  manager worker [21671] at slot 1 generation 1 detaching cleanly
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-3] ERROR:  found xmax 438 from before relfrozenxid 575242479
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-4] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_20862"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-5] ERROR:  found xmax 55387931 from before relfrozenxid 575277757
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-6] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_11109"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-7] ERROR:  invalid page in block 8755 of relation base/16385/1508406
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-8] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_14016"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-9] ERROR:  found xmax 636 from before relfrozenxid 575359580
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-10] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_16673"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-11] ERROR:  invalid page in block 1955 of relation base/16385/1527429
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-12] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_gps_19006"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-13] ERROR:  found xmax 515 from before relfrozenxid 575423024
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-14] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_10723"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-15] ERROR:  invalid page in block 47546 of relation base/16385/1551827
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-16] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_11615"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-17] ERROR:  invalid page in block 11395 of relation base/16385/1553243
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-18] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_11863"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-19] ERROR:  found xmax 545 from before relfrozenxid 575604035
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-20] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_12610"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-21] ERROR:  found xmax 312 from before relfrozenxid 575664399
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-22] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_13053"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-23] ERROR:  found xmin 171352576 from before relfrozenxid 575738749
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-24] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_14098"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-25] ERROR:  found xmax 694 from before relfrozenxid 575750219
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-26] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_14210"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-27] ERROR:  found xmax 65 from before relfrozenxid 575779140
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-28] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_14299"
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-29] ERROR:  found xmax 344 from before relfrozenxid 575817146
2019-03-14 11:54:12 UTC [21663-30] CONTEXT:  automatic vacuum of table "irzdb.public.z_io_14396"
```

И так по кругу - в течении 5 минут все время поднимается и падает. 
После анализа лога пало подозрение на ОЗУ. Был сделан strace процесса и действительно - cannot allocate memory. 
Получается, что процесс запрашивает такое количество памяти, которое не может быть выделено. Все бы ничего, НО:

```
# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32184       8709      23475          0        154       7506
-/+ buffers/cache:       1048      31136
Swap:        16383          0      16383

# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 257361
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 257361
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Подскажите, в какую сторону смотреть?

Comment: ОЗУ прогнал memtester'ом, HDD - badblock'ом. Ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1):

База повреждена физически.

Непосредственно сложилась по приведённому логу вот тут:

> PANIC:  corrupted item pointer: offset = 28672, length = 6939

Потому что [такого быть не может.](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/src/backend/storage/page/bufpage.c#L892) Следовательно, база повреждена. Поэтому `PANIC` и складываем базу.

Почему повреждена? Сомнительно что получится выяснить. Может быть вы сами отстрелили себе ноги выключив `fsync`. Или какой `pg_resetxlog` сделали не открывая к тому документацию. Может быть у вас какие-то ещё посторонние модули стоят в пространстве ядра базы помимо явно видимого `pglogical` и делают что-то сильно не то.

> MultiXactId 374398121 has not been created yet -- apparent wraparound

[Ошибка чуть меньшего уровня](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/src/backend/access/transam/multixact.c#L1285), но очень большой важности. Страница выглядит так, будто пропущен транзакционный wraparound. Так тоже быть не может без вмешательства извне.

`invalid page in block` однозначно заявляет, что [с диска прочли какой-то мусор](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/src/backend/storage/buffer/bufmgr.c#L915) вместо данных. Аналогично [`found xmax %u from before relfrozenxid`](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/REL9_6_STABLE/src/backend/access/heap/heapam.c#L6778) - то что не происходит само по себе.

В отдельности каждая из ошибок означает, что база повреждена. А уж в комплекте - никто не скажет, что у вас вместо данных.

### Что делать

восстанавливаться из бекапа. Если бекап в виде логического дампа - то обязательно в чистый, с нуля инициализированный кластер. Хорошая возможность попутно включить `data_checksum`. Затем из старого кластера вычитывать всё что получится вычитать. Лучше перевести в `readonly` стартовав базу в [`standby_mode = on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/standby-settings.html) и не указывая `primary_connninfo` или `restore_command`.

К прочитанным данным отнестись внимательно. Возможно пропущен wraparound и вы сможете получать уже удалённые версии строк, не получать некоторые которые ваше приложение считает живыми и любые фокусы от возможно повреждённых индексов.